# Go runtime logging verbosity change

Tags: logging, go, runtime

I need to change logging verbosity/level while Golang application is running, without restarting

I came from PHP where there are several logging frameworks supporting DB-based configuration change on run-time

What's the most standard/canonical way to achieve this kind of functionality in Go?

Comment: The stdlib logger doesn't have logging levels, so this seems like a request for a third-party library, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Off-topic though it may be, the most common libs I see for level-based logging are [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) and [go-logging](https://github.com/op/go-logging).  Both support runtime alteration of the log level without application restart, though neither are specifically oriented around DB-specified configuration (or runtime config manipulation via DB values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a library like https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus that has built in logging levels. Also can do structured logging

Comment: Logrus + few lines of goroutine to check loglevel from database in the loop did the trick. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I think question is how to change the log level at run time. Like its there in logback / log4j2.